# Can I install different build number of sql server 2016?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

In my laptop, I installed **Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU14) (KB4564903) - 13.0.5830.85 (X64)** but somehow I need to install **Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-GDR) (KB4293802) - 13.0.5081.1 (X64)** in my pc.

For that do I need to uninstall the previous version or can I install without uninstalling?

Comment: Why do you want to revert to SP2-GDR?

Comment: I am updating database schema of my production instance to the VM. In one VM which has SP2-GDR working fine but in SP2-CU14 not working. For that reason, I decided to update sql server to SP2-GDR.

Comment: That's not an "update", that's a revert (SP2-GDR is older than SP2-CU14, see the [build list](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3177312/sql-server-2016-build-versions)). If something isn't working on the more recent version, why not tell us what it is you're trying to do and explain why it isn't working. Downgrading is a clear example of an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Answer (score 0):

You need to unistall the newer version and later install the older one.
It's possible to update but not to revert.